# Define a new command to wrap \cref

Tags: expl3, exam, xparse, comma-separated-list

I am typesetting an MCQ exam paper. There are a few questions where there exists a block of information, and the student is prompted to use that information to answer several questions that follow, for instance:

```
(in boldface) Use the following information to answer questions 3 to 5. 

Here is some information. Use this. This is useful. Lorem ipsum.
```

I would like to make this easier, by defining a command that allows typesetters to add the questions as a comma-separated list, like such: `\useinfo{3,4,5}{Here is some information. Use this. This is useful. Lorem ipsum.}`

If users could type the comma-separated list in the vein of TikZ lists, such as `\useinfo{3,..,6}{...}`, this ought to print `Use the following ... questions 3, 4, 5, and 6.`

This command would pipe the numbers in the first argument into `\cref{}` provided by the `cleveref` package, and the second argument would be the actual information needed, placed below the `Use the following...` line and separated by a parskip.

Now, here's a first attempt:

```latex
\providecommand{\useinfo}[2]{
    \begin{EnvFullwidth}
        \textbf{Use the following information to answer \cref*{#1}}.
        
        #2
    \end{EnvFullwidth}
}
```

This implementation has two problems:

1. The user has to manually type `question@x` (this is provided by the `exam` class), rather than simply the question number alone, as mentioned above.
2. The parskip does not show up.

How may I fix this, so that each number provided by the user is prepended by a `question@` before being passed on to the `\cref` command?

Comment: Assuming each question numbered `n` is associated with a `\label` directive of the form `q:n`, could you replace `\useinfo{3,..,6}` with `\crefange{q:3}{q:6}`?

Comment: @Mico thanks for your comment. My key question was providing a command such that the user would not need to type the `q:` at all. The `exam` class already automatically generates labels for each question, part and subpart, so I was intending to make use of that, directly.